# Problem in MacTeX: package pdftex.def Error: File `./image1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics, eps, mactex, epstopdf

I have a problem using MacTeX (distribution TeXLive-2013 Intel 64) in Mac OS X 10.9.2, with the IDE TeXstudio 2.7.0. I am trying to include an EPS figure in my document (as I used to do in Windows), but I get the following error:

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `./image1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not
>   found \includegraphics{image1.eps}

My minimal .tex file is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{image1.eps}

\end{document}
```

I have tried some tips I found in previous posts in various forums:

-> I included the following line in `PdfLaTeX/usr/texbin/pdflatex`: `--shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

-> I added the `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}` line, just in case the file `image1.eps` can not be found in the right path.

But it doesn't work...

Please, does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can indent your code by 4 spaces in order to mark the code as such. Normally we don't put "thanks" or our Names in the post, as it is already signed by you in the right bottom corner. Maybe you sign in to get a nicer name than user49874. When signed in, you will be able to up-vote and accept answers.

Comment: Has this been resolved? If not, please make the file `image1.eps` available for download and add a link here.